# How do I change the icon of an Alert dialog?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, alert

I want to change following default icon of a alert message. How can I do it?

This is what I want to change:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to change the Icon. It means I want to change that blue icon to something else. Not to change alret type

Comment: There are 4 built-in types for an alert: WARNING, INFORMATION, CONFIRMATION, ERROR, and NONE. All have their own icons (except NONE, which does not have an icon). You simply set the alert type you want when you create the alert: `Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING)`, for example.

Comment: If, however, you are looking for a way to specify your own graphic for the icon, please update your question to say so.

Comment: Alert is-a Dialog ... so the answer can be found in its [api doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) ;) BTW, reading api is a good means to learn what's available and keep up-to-date on changes .. we all need to do it again and again :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

First of all, the `Alert` class accepts an `AlertType` parameter when creating the alert. There are 5 built-in options to choose from, each with it's own icon:

`INFORMATION`, `CONFIRMATION`, `WARNING`, `ERROR`, and `NONE` (which provides no icon at all).

You can select one of these icons when creating the `Alert` by passing the `AlertType` to the constructor:

`Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);`

[image: ERROR screenshot]

---

If, however, you want to provide your own icon image, you can do so by accessing the `dialogPane` of the `Alert` and setting the `graphic` property:

```
alert.getDialogPane().setGraphic(new ImageView("your_icon.png"));
```

Below is a simple application that demonstrates how to use a custom icon image for the `Alert`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Build the Alert
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Alert Test");
        alert.setHeaderText("This uses a custom icon!");

        // Create the ImageView we want to use for the icon
        ImageView icon = new ImageView("your_icon.png");

        // The standard Alert icon size is 48x48, so let's resize our icon to match
        icon.setFitHeight(48);
        icon.setFitWidth(48);

        // Set our new ImageView as the alert's icon
        alert.getDialogPane().setGraphic(icon);
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

And the resulting `Alert`:

[image: Custom Icon Alert]

---

**Note:** As Sai Dandem's equally-valid answer illustrates, you are not restricted to using an `ImageView` for the graphic. The `setGraphic()` method accepts any `Node` object, so you could just as easily pass a `Button`, `Hyperlink`, or other UI component.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from what @Zephyr has already mentioned, if you want to set your own custom icon/graphic at the place where you pointed in your screenshot, use setGraphic() method of `javafx.scene.control.Dialog` class.

In the below code, though the alertType is INFORMATION, it will override the predefined icon with the provided graphic node.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setTitle("My Title");
alert.setContentText("My Content text");
alert.setHeaderText("My Header");
alert.setGraphic(new Button("My Graphic"));
alert.show();
```

[image]